# Ascii doc syntaxes not provide consistent output & not working as expected

Tags: ascii, asciidoc

I have a .adoc file and it has a table with 3 columns. The table simply represents some HTTP codes with their status code, meanings, and methods.

[image]

This is the code I used to generate the above table.

```
[cols="10%,70%,20%",options="header",]
|=======================================================================
|Code |Meaning |Methods
|[[status-code-502]]{502}|
Gateway error response code indicates that the server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from the upstream server.
|{ALL}

|[[status-code-503]]{503}|
Service Unavailable - service is (temporarily) not available (e.g. if a
required component or downstream service is not available) -- client retry may
be sensible. If possible, the service should indicate how long the client
should wait by setting the {Retry-After} header.
|{ALL}

|[[status-code-54]]{504}|
Gateway error response code indicates that the server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, did not get a response in time from the upstream server that it needed in order to complete the request.
|{ALL}
|=======================================================================
```

My question is when I'm using the same structure of code, why do the codes 502 and 504 show like "{502}" & "{504}", and without anchor tag and bold text? Appreciate it if someone could explain this and give a solution.

Comment: `{502}`, `{503}`, `{504}`, and `{ALL}` are [user defined document attributes](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/attributes/document-attributes/). However, it appears that only two of them have been defined elsewhere in your document.

Comment: Could you elaborate more please.

Comment: Why does `{503}` look like **`503`** and why does `{ALL}` look like `<all>`? There must be a line somewhere in your document that defines that custom behaviour.